# printing wrong decimal

Tags: java

```
arr[i]=s+t-Math.abs(s-j)/2;
```

here is the line, `s= 600 j = 631 t =60` , the answer should be `645.5` but it prints `645.0`. 
arr[] is double

Comment: are `s` `j` and `t` integers?

Comment: We need to see the declarations of all your variables.

Comment: yes they are of type int

Comment: ^As they said, how did you declare your variables? If they are `ints` then it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the types of `s` and `j` are `int`, you must be performing Java's integer division, which results in an `int`.  `s-j` results in `-31`, and the [`Math.abs` overload that takes an `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) is called, and `31` is returned.  Integer division in Java means that `31/2` is `15` the `int`, not `15.5` the `double`.

Use the floating-point literal `2.0` to force floating-point division (or cast one of the `/` operands to a `double`):

```
arr[i]=s+t-Math.abs(s-j)/2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are losing precision while dividing ints .Put a cast around the division

```
arr[i]= s+ t- (double) Math.abs(s-j)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting.

`arr[i]=s+t-Math.abs(s-j)/2.0;`

The trick here is that when you do divide by 2 it will give you an integer answer. So for your case( Math.abs(-31)/2 -> **15** instead of **15.5**. and thus will truncate the .5

Therefore, by adding the 2.0 it will give you a double answer that is 15.5 and give you the desired solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably `s-j` is an integer-valued (or long-valued) expression in your example, which makes Java select an integer/long valued `Math.abs(...)` call, returning an integer/long value. When dividing integer values, the decimal places are truncated. For example, `3 / 2` becomes 1, `15 / 2` becomes 7.

An easy way to make the expression evaluated with floating point math, is to divide by `2.0` instead:

```
arr[i] = s + t - Math.abs(s-j) / 2.0;
```

These other writing styles will work too:

```
arr[i] = s + t - Math.abs(s-j) / 2.;
arr[i] = s + t - Math.abs(s-j) / 2f;
arr[i] = s + t - Math.abs(s-j) / 2d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set 2f in order to make a decimal division (now you are doing a integer division in Math.abs(s-j)/2)

Then your code should be

```
arr[i] = s + t - Math.abs(s-j)/2f;
```